# Mean IO - What are the email service providers for gmail?

Tags: node.js, email, mean.io

In MEAN.IO, in the config section you can set the email service provider, what there is no documentation on what the options are. I want to use google apps. For the provider do I just put google or gmail or what?

Answer (score 0):

It's just 'Gmail'. Seems pretty simple. Should be in the documentation. Still don't know what the other options are.